# Google Earth doesn't load in Chromium

Tags: google-earth

Some minutes after going to https://earth.google.com/web/ in Chromium 62.0.3202.75 on Linux it still displays just "Google Earth" and a background image. The only issues in the network tab is that URLs `https://people-pa.clients6.google.com/v2/people:batchGet?[…]` and `https://clients5.google.com/log?authuser=0` return HTTP 401. I won't use Chrome, and it doesn't yet support Firefox, so I'm kind of stumped.

1. Do I need to be authenticated to any Google services to use Google Earth?
2. Is Chromium not supported?

Comment: You might be right. Can this be migrated?

Answer (score 2):

Besides you and me, many others reported that the new version doesn't run in Chromium.  There was lot of complaining on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/66ao68/new_version_of_google_earth_runs_on_chrome_only/) and [hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14137537) when it happened in April 2017.

I found this [Google Earth blog post](https://medium.com/google-earth/earth-on-web-the-road-to-cross-browser-7338e0f46278) from October 2017.  They're porting the new Google Earth from their old binaries-on-the-web scheme, [Native Client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client), to the newer standard [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly).  They talk about showing a demo running in Chrome, Firefox, and Chromium.  They say "As WebAssembly’s threading support continues to grow in popularity with browsers, we look forward to launching in a browser near you!"  They don't give a date.

(And tho maybe redundant, I can tell you that being logged in with Google made no difference. That was Chromium on Linux, too, but I really want to run it in Firefox.)